# How to debug and fix "SSL handshake failed" for Kafka broker in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, ssl, apache-kafka, docker-compose, opa

**ULTIMATE GOAL:**

I make a research trying to understand how Kafka and OPA Plugin integrated between each other and how easy it will be to use OPA Plugin in production.

**STEPS:**

I followed [OPA Policy Agent tutorial](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/kafka-authorization/). The part, I am stuck on is how to make Broker work and recognise `localhost` in the docker-compose setup.

My `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.21.4
    volumes:
      - "./bundles:/usr/share/nginx/html"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
  opa:
    image: openpolicyagent/opa:0.51.0
    ports:
      - "8181:8181"
    command:
      - "run"
      - "--server"
      - "--set=decision_logs.console=true"
      - "--set=services.authz.url=http://nginx"
      - "--set=bundles.authz.service=authz"
      - "--set=bundles.authz.resource=bundle.tar.gz"
    depends_on:
      - nginx
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.1
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
      - ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181
  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.1
    ports:
      - "9093:9093"
    environment:
      # Set cache expiry to low value for development in order to see decisions
      KAFKA_OPA_AUTHORIZER_CACHE_EXPIRE_AFTER_SECONDS: 10
      KAFKA_OPA_AUTHORIZER_URL: http://opa:8181/v1/data/kafka/authz/allow
      KAFKA_AUTHORIZER_CLASS_NAME: org.openpolicyagent.kafka.OpaAuthorizer
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: SSL://localhost:9093
      KAFKA_SECURITY_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL: SSL
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_FILENAME: server.keystore
      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_CREDENTIALS: credentials.txt
      KAFKA_SSL_KEY_CREDENTIALS: credentials.txt
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_FILENAME: server.truststore
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_CREDENTIALS: credentials.txt
      KAFKA_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH: required
      # KAFKA_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM: ""
      # KAFKA_PRODUCER_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM: ""
      # KAFKA_CONSUMER_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM: ""
      CLASSPATH: "/plugin/*"
    volumes:
      - "./plugin:/plugin"
      - "./cert/server:/etc/kafka/secrets"
    depends_on:
      - opa
      - zookeeper
```

The folder structure is the same as in tutorial with generated certificates etc.

The stack trace of the error is below:

```
broker_1     | [2023-04-27 08:40:46,391] INFO [Controller id=1, targetBrokerId=1] Failed authentication with localhost/127.0.0.1 (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
broker_1     | [2023-04-27 08:40:46,392] ERROR [Controller id=1, targetBrokerId=1] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9093) failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
broker_1     | [2023-04-27 08:40:46,393] WARN [RequestSendThread controllerId=1] Controller 1's connection to broker localhost:9093 (id: 1 rack: null) was unsuccessful (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)
broker_1     | org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed
broker_1     | Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No name matching localhost found
broker_1     |  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
broker_1     |  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:349)
broker_1     |  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:292)
broker_1     |  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:287)
broker_1     |  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1357)
broker_1     |  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1232)
broker_1     |  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1175)
broker_1     |  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
broker_1     |  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
broker_1     |  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1074)
broker_1     |  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1061)
broker_1     |  at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
broker_1     |  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1008)
broker_1     |  at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.runDelegatedTasks(SslTransportLayer.java:430)
broker_1     |  at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshakeUnwrap(SslTransportLayer.java:514)
broker_1     |  at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.doHandshake(SslTransportLayer.java:368)
broker_1     |  at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshake(SslTransportLayer.java:291)
broker_1     |  at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.prepare(KafkaChannel.java:178)
broker_1     |  at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:543)
broker_1     |  at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481)
broker_1     |  at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:561)
broker_1     |  at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.awaitReady(NetworkClientUtils.java:74)
broker_1     |  at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.brokerReady(ControllerChannelManager.scala:292)
broker_1     |  at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.doWork(ControllerChannelManager.scala:246)
broker_1     |  at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:96)
broker_1     | Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found
broker_1     |  at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(HostnameChecker.java:234)
broker_1     |  at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:103)
broker_1     |  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:455)
broker_1     |  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:429)
broker_1     |  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:283)
broker_1     |  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:141)
broker_1     |  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1335)
broker_1     |  ... 20 more
```

**DEBUGGING STEPS:**

1. I tried disable SSL check by this parameters:

```
KAFKA_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM: ""
KAFKA_PRODUCER_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM: ""
KAFKA_CONSUMER_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM: ""
```

It leaves me with the situation when messages aren't acknowledged and broker isn't reachable.

2. I tried changing `localhost` to `internal.docker.host` and to `0.0.0.0`

internal.docker.host gives the same error. 0.0.0.0 simply non-routable.

I also looked for other answers but not much information, I could operate with. Most of them nailed down to those 2 above.

Version changing didn't help much as Kafka is evolving itself and in new versions there are other challenges and required changes to the docker-compose (for example deprecated Zookeeper).

**MACHINE INFO:**

For running docker, I use `colima` engine which is a decent alternative to `docker` engine from Docker Inc.

Machine is MacOS.

**QUESTION:**

What can I do to fix this current issue? Or maybe land to another more common, easier to fix issue?